# setarch on a Mac

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, unix

I am trying to compile a version of python on my Mac that requires the "setarch" command, but that command does not appear in my PATH (I'm running OSX 10.8.3, with XCode 4.6.2 installed).  Is there a version of setarch for the Mac?

Answer (score 5):

`setarch` is a low-level unportable Linux-specific command.

MacOS does have a similar command: [arch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/arch.1.html).

For example:

```
$ arch -i386 python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'
2147483647
$ arch -x86_64 python -c 'import sys; print sys.maxint'
9223372036854775807
```

You can see that Python's idea of the biggest possible integer changes depending on whether you force it to run in 32-bit or 64-bit mode.

See also "[How to launch applications in 32 bit from Terminal in Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/questions/76730/how-to-launch-applications-in-32-bit-from-terminal-in-snow-leopard)".

Comment: And Python of course still has it's cool 32-bit shorthand for quickly running 32-bit-dependant apps in 64-bit environments `$ python-32 main.py`. Used a lot for solutions like `wxPython`, which still need to be run in 32-bit.